# outside of the parent before calling draggable({containment : "parent"})

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When i use `.draggable` and the element is outside of the parent before calling `draggable({containment : "parent"})`

it is only placed inside the parent after dragging it, I need to immediately position it into the parent, after calling draggable

Here is an example: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ddwsL0sc/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the correct solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/ddwsL0sc/12/

it was possible to call the internal functions

```
$(".draggable").draggable({containment : "parent"});
$('.draggable').draggable().data("ui-draggable")._mouseStart({pageX:0, pageY:0});
$('.draggable').draggable().data("ui-draggable")._mouseDrag({});
$('.draggable').draggable().data("ui-draggable")._mouseStop({});
```

Comment: yes, (+1), can you explain what `_mouseDrag({})`(mouseInteraction) is doing with the data of `ui-draggable`. The documentation is not really helpful here.

Comment: i found the sourcecode here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/800d76ac17345b6016f3d067b41a757ebd2c9bb8/ui/widgets/draggable.js i'm just simulating a mouse drag

Answer (score 1):

You can use `create( event, ui )` event of jquery draggable.

It is **Triggered when the draggable is created.**

Solution :

```
     $('.draggable').draggable({
  containment: "parent"
}, {
  create: function(event, ui) {
    var parent1 = $(this).parent();
    var top = $(this).offset().top;
    var left = $(this).offset().left;
    var width = $(this).width();
    var height = $(this).height();
    console.log(top+height);
 if (left < parent1.offset().left){
       $(this).offset({left: $(this).parent().offset().left});
    }
    if (top < parent1.offset().top){
        $(this).offset({top: $(this).parent().offset().top});
    }
    if ((left + width > parent1.width()+parent1.offset().left)){
         $(this).offset({left: ($(this).parent().offset().left+parent1.widhth()-width)});
    }
    if(top + height > parent1.height()+parent1.offset().top){
         $(this).offset({top: ($(this).parent().offset().top+parent1.height()-height)});
    }    
  }
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ddwsL0sc/11/)

Reference: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-create

Comment: this will move the el even when it is inside the parent, isnt it possible to trigger the function which is called while dragging?

Comment: yes, there is a method called drag `drag: function(event, ui){..}`. But you want the draggable div to be inside parent div, when the draggable is create. so we should use `create`. see the edited answer. Here I am checking whether the div is inside or not.

Comment: this will set the draggable to the top left, even when it overlaps the parent on the right side... is it not possible to call the jquery-function which keeps the draggable inside the parent while dragging?

Comment: "is it not possible to call the jquery-function which keeps the draggable inside the parent while dragging?"....' while dragging ' it is already coming inside the parent. What exactly you want .can you explain in more details ?

Comment: you reimplement the code which must already be presend in jquery-ui, your code works, but is it not possible to call function from jquery-ui?

Comment: I don't think there's any function for this (at least I am not aware of it). You need to implement this on your own. also If you want..you can make a separate function for checking(all `if`s in 1 function) and thus you can check the conditions by calling that function from different draggable elements. just make `check_div_in_or_out = function($this){..}`